# How to total sum of table using for loop in php

Tags: php

I created table using multi for loop and i get it result but i want result to total sum of table like :

My code are given below :

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
{   

    for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        $total = $i*$j;
        $sum = $total+$j;
        echo "<td>$i * $j = ".$total."</td>";  
    }
    echo "</tr>" ;
    echo "<br/>" ;
}
```

and My output is :

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
```

But I Want result to total get multiply value like :

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3 1+2+3 = 6

2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6 2+4+6 = 12
```

I Appreciate if anyone know this answer.

Comment: In your original attempt you did not try to add up the results of each multiplication. You seem to be doing it fine. Just need to add in that last step in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the total for each loop.

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
{   
$sum =0; // initiate sum variable with 0
    for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++)
    {
        $total = $i*$j;
        $sum += $total; // add total value to sum
        echo "$i * $j = ".$total."\n";  
    }

    echo "Sum = $sum\n" ; // echo sum value
}
```

Out Put:

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
Sum = 6
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
Sum = 12
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Ravinder Reddy. Really your calculation is perfect and I really Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to do the sum.
En at the end of the 2d loop, do the echo.
You did a mistake with $sum = $total+$j; It is : $sum = $total+$sum;

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
{   
$sum = 0;

for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $total = $i*$j;
    $sum = $total+$sum;
    echo "<td>$i * $j = ".$total."</td>";  
}
echo "</tr>" ;
echo "<tr><td>SUM : ".$sum."</td></tr>";
echo "<br/>" ;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
    {   
    $k ='';
    $result ='0';
    for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        $total = $i*$j;
        $sum = $total+$j;
        echo "<td>$i * $j = ".$total."</td>";  
        $result += $total;
        $k.= " $total + ";
        if($j == 3)
        {
            $k.= " $total";
        }
    }

    echo "<td>" ;
    echo "$k = $result";
    echo "</td>" ;  
    echo "</tr>" ;  
    echo "<br/>" ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
echo "<table>";
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
{   
    $sum =0;
    $str = "";
    for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        $total = $i*$j;
        $sum = $total+$sum;
        echo "<td>$i * $j = ".$total."</td></tr>"; 
        $str = "$str $total +";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>".substr($str,0, strlen($str)-1)." =  $sum</td></tr>" ;
    echo "<br/>" ;
}
echo "</table>";
```